# How can I use speech recognition from IE9 like Chrome 11 beta can?

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, speech-recognition

Can someone tell me how to use HTML5's speech recognition support with IE9 (relevant web page explaining how would be great)?  Or does only Google Chrome 11 beta have that support?

-- roschler

Answer (score 1):

It's a WebKit experiment, it's not yet been accepted into any W3C or WHATWG spec, there is currently no such thing as 'HTML5 Speech Recognition' just [a proposal](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html).  If it does get accepted, and Microsoft continue to follow their [site ready](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/12/21/html5-site-ready-and-experimental.aspx) policy, then you can probably expect to see it in either IE11 or IE12.